# I can't get data from api to react

Tags: reactjs

I have problems getting data from api to react, i think there is a logical error, can you help me? I don't think i have any error on Visual Studio on back-end because it worked well on Postman, but in Visual Studio Code i have this problem.
**Also i am working with .net core 5.0 and the video that i'm following uses 3.1.** My code is this:
.env file:

```
REACT_APP_API=http://localhost:53535/api/
REACT_APP_PHOTOPATH=http://localhost:53535/Photos/
```

.Positions.js

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {Table} from 'react-bootstrap';

import {Button,ButtonToolbar} from 'react-bootstrap';
import {AddPosModal} from './AddPosModal';

export class Positions extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={deps:[], addModalShow:false}
    }

    refreshList(){
        fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API+'positions')
        .then(response=>response.json())
        .then(data=>{
            this.setState({deps:data});
        });
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.refreshList();
    }

    componentDidUpdate(){
        this.refreshList();
    }

    render(){
        const {deps}=this.state;
        let addModalClose=()=>this.setState({addModalShow:false});
        return(
            <div>
                <Table className="at-4" striped bordered hover size="sm">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>PositionID</th>
                            <th>Position</th>
                            <th>Options</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {deps.map(pos=>
                            <tr key={pos.PositionID}>
                                <td>{pos.PositionID}</td>
                                <td>{pos.Position}</td>
                                <td>Edit / Delete</td>
                            </tr>)}
                    </tbody>    
                </Table>

<ButtonToolbar>
    <Button variant='primary'
        onClick={()=>this.setState({addModalShow:true})}>
            Add Position
        </Button>

        <AddPosModal show={this.state.addModalShow}
        onHide={addModalClose}></AddPosModal>

</ButtonToolbar>

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what is the problem exactly? In this state, your question will be closed due to lack of debugging details.

Comment: I am watching this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gpfP60KjmZU&t=2836s&ab_channel=ArtofEngineer and at the 47:07 minute i don't get any data. I don't know where is the problem

Comment: Impossible to help you without giving any debugging details. Not sure what you mean by "...47:07 minute i don't get any data". Be specific and don't force people to watch parts of videos just to grasp the context of your exact problem and figuring out how to puzzle the pieces of your cryptic problem description.

Comment: I am using api .net core, postman, sql for the back-end and everything works fine. My localhost api is :5000 in Postman. In react for front-end at the .env file he writes REACT_APP_API 'http://localhost/53535/api/'. The backend API url's port is 5000. I don't know which path is correct and neither of them works for me

Comment: @zhulien do i need to import anything else on my code and i am working with .net core 5.0 and the video that im following uses 3.1. Is there any difference on fetching data?

Answer (score 1):

A potential error when handling different api endpoints is in the following function. As a commentor explained this is not the reason that causes this error, see it is a clean-code best practice in case you have to handle different endpoints later :)
The function:

```
refreshList(){
    fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API+'positions')
```

There „positions“ is a static string, not a dynamic variable of type string.

It should look like this (In Typescript):

```
refreshList(thePosition: string){
    fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API + thePosition)
```

Comment: How is this an error? It results in a `http://localhost:53535/api/positions/`, exactly what OP wants to fetch. He is simply concatenating the literal string `positions` to the base api address.

Comment: You are absolutely right! My answer does not solve the problem. I just saw this as a potential error source when handling different endpoints and thought  maybe this is the error. I will edit my answer. Thank you!

Comment: I am watching this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gpfP60KjmZU&t=2836s&ab_channel=ArtofEngineer and at the 47:07 minute i don't get any data. I don't know where is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently doing a look-up on React for an anticipated project and watching the video too. at 47min no data came out. After reviewing the code, ensure the Python Backend is running fine. It worked fine after I have my code thus:

**Department Class:**

```js
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {Table} from 'react-bootstrap';

export class Department extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={deps:[]}
    }

    refreshList(){
        fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API+'department')
        .then(response=>response.json())
        .then(data=>{
            this.setState({deps:data});
        });
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.refreshList();
    }

    componentDidUpdate(){
        this.refreshList();
    }

    render(){
        const {deps} = this.state;
        return(
            <div>
                <Table className="mt-4" striped bordered hover size="sm">
                  <thead>
                      <tr>
                      <th>DepartmentId</th>
                      <th>DepartmentName</th>
                      <th>Options</th>
                      </tr>
                  </thead> 
                  <tbody>
                      {deps.map(dep=>
                        <tr key={dep.DepartmentId}>
                            <td>{dep.DepartmentId}</td>
                            <td>{dep.DepartmentName}</td>
                            <td>Edit/Delete</td>
                            
                        </tr>)}
                  </tbody>
                </Table>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Also, ensure your router dom version is consistent in App.js.

```js
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

import {Home} from './Home';
import {Department} from './Department';
import {Employee} from './Employee';
import {Navigation} from './Navigation';

import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
  
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <div className="container">
      <h3 className="m-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
        React Class
      </h3>

      <Navigation/>

      <Switch>
        <Route path='/' component={Home} exact/>
        <Route path='/department' component={Department}/>
        <Route path='/employee' component={Employee}/>
      </Switch>
    </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```